# PhpStorm - How to escape dollar sign (php variable) in File Template?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a PhpStorm Php file template under *Editor > File and Code Templates*:

[image: PhpStorm File Template]

According to the [linked Apache Velocity Docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Velocity_Template_Language_VTL:_An_Introduction) to escape a dollar sign a back slash should be used:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
#parse("PHP File Header.php")
#if (${NAMESPACE})
namespace ${NAMESPACE};
#end

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class ${NAME} implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function transform(\$value)
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

But when I select the template when creating a class, the backslash stays:

[image: Use Template]

File output:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace SomeProject\SomeBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class TestTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function transform(\$value)
    {
        return ;
    }

    public function reverseTransform()
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

It works when i directly select the template and not create class, but then the namespace is not taken automatically...

#### So how do i escape the dollar sign properly? Is that a known bug?

Comment: *"Is that a known bug?"* No bugs here. You just need to read the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-template-variables.html# The best way is to use `${DS}` when you need to insert the dollar sign.

Comment: Thank you, didn't really pay attention to the predefined variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per PhpStorm help page (link below) the best way would be to use predefined `${DS}` variable if you need to have `$` (dollar sign) in the file template output.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-template-variables.html